# Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play

I have app on Play store on production mode which was showing above error(**production version is 16**), later I fix the GCP API key error and uploaded app first for beta testing(**beta release version is 23**), while submitting app it showing **update rejected** because of GCP API key but in error message it showing **Affects APK version 16** only. Why my new version is not live on beta? How to identify and fix it?

About my GCP key fix: previuosly I had google map key in my manifest file(till production 16), later I shift google-map-key to gradle.properties file(beta version 23), do I need to shift google map key to any other place to avoid these rejection?

Comment: I used to fix this by storing the key in NDK file (C++)

Comment: just a wild guess: try to deactivate old v 16 APK

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko16 is live production version, without validating new version on beta i cannot deactivate it, on beta I am trying to upload new version but unable to see as google showing it "update rejected" but with in error description showing affected version api 16 as mentioned above.